# .htaccess rewrite "/book.php?id=1234" to "/book/1234"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect-loop

This is what I have so far in my development environment:

```
php_value error_log log/php.log
php_value display_errors 1
php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off

RewriteEngine On

# remove slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ajax.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]

# /file to file.php
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I've tried a lot of variants of this rule but I always get a 500 error:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book.php?url=$1 [L]
```

And this is in my Apache's error.log:

```
[Fri Jul 27 19:56:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

What am I missing, why the redirect loop?

Comment: also, is there a way to make rules completely independent from the domain? I'd like to avoid changing this file in local/qa/prod environments

Comment: Or simply `RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]`.
And last but not least, try to add: `RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` as written appears to be trying to do opposite of what your question headline is saying.  You say that you want `htaccess rewrite /book.php?id=1234 to /book/1234`, but your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Is adding a query string parameter.

The RewriteRule below will rewrite `rewrite /book.php?id=1234 to /book/1234`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^book\.php$ /book/%1? [L]
```

Also, if you really wish to go the other way, i.e. rewrite `/book/1234` to `/book.php?id=1234` the following should do that:

```
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
# in htaccess file write this
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+) book.php?id=$i

# and in you html or php file call

book.php?id=$i
```

page by

```
book/$i
```

you are done.