# .htaccess URL rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I'm trying to learn how to rewrite URL's within htaccess files.
If anyone can give me some good links that would be brilliant.

I'm trying to aim to rewrite this:
http://www.domainname.co.uk/news/newsSingle.php?ID=9

to this:
http://www.domainname.co.uk/news/category-name/post-name.php

I have the category-name & post-name within the database for each matching ID.
Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a look at

1. [9lessons.info](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html)
2. [Media Temple](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)
3. [Stack Overflow .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)

Hope these help you find the answer.