# How do I make a URL to look like "/lobby/1" instead of "/lobby.php?id=1"?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to make a URL to look like this:

```
http://example.com/lobby/1
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/lobby.php?id=1
```

I know I can do this with .htaccess but I couldn't find a way how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite /book.php?id=1234 to /book/1234](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)

Answer (score 0):

There are several already answered questions, such as [.htaccess rewrite "/book.php?id=1234" to "/book/1234"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^ lobby\.php$ /lobby/%1? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /lobby\.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /lobby/%1? [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^lobby/([0-9]+)/?$ /lobby.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: tried this, when i go to the lobby.php?id=1 it redirects me to lobby/1 but it says "404 not found".

Comment: @Roy is your htaccess located in root folder?

Comment: its on the www folder with the rest of the files. @starkeen

Comment: Not Found The requested URL /lobby/1 was not found on this server. after updating

Comment: Perhaps Multiviews is on. Turn it off with `Options -Multiviews`. Truthfully, however, I am not sure if this is, in fact, the real issue here.

Comment: @MikeRockett now i can see the page but i dont see the styling, all the css and js files are treated like its a folder. there is a way to fix it?

Comment: You need to reference front end assets relative to the root of your site. Just make sure each asset is referenced with a `/` at the beginning. Or set `<base href="/">` in your `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

try this!

in htaccess file write this

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^lobby/([0-9]+) lobby.php?id=$i

and in you html or php file call
lobby.php?id=$i

page by

lobby/$i

you are done.