# PHP GET Method without index.php?id=XXX

Tags: php, html, apache

I have written (in `PHP` and `PDO`) a link shrinker that works with the `GET` method `(index.php?id=1)` but I want it like this: `domain.com/[ID]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234

Comment: Read up on URL rewriting. That's what you seem to be looking for. But how you must implement it depends on which web server you are using, so this question is missing details for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create .htaccess file in your main folder and write the below content inside the file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Result

domain.com/1 = domain.com/index.php?id=1

domain.com/home = domain.com/index.php?id=home

domain.com/ID = domain.com/index.php?id=ID