# URL Conversion using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to convert a the following URL

http://mughalspak.com/index.php?func=page_cms&cat_id=8&page_id=33&page_banner_image=

to

http://mughalspak.com/carriers

Comment: please elaborate more to get answer what are you using like framework

Comment: on which basis above URL will convert. As there are values which creating unique url. You can use this two function- `encodeURIComponent(str)` and `encodeURI(str)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

use htaccess [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280383/php-get-method-without-index-phpid-xxx/36280603#36280603)

**or you can use something below to generate friendly URL**

**STEPS**

1. Store all the friendly URL texts into database. Should be unique. Remove all the special characters. replace white space by underscores.
2. use .htaccess to rewrite url, and link to a specific php file to identify the actual page.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?func=redirectpage&var=$1 [L]
   ```
3. In the page.php, search database for the unique $var, Generate the link and use require()