# How do I upload my localhost site to an online server?

Tags: php, apache, ftp

Now I know that you have to FTP the files to the server but I'm more confused about the directory structure... Let me explain..

**Here is the localhost directory structure** 
C:/wamp/www/store/{Here is the entire project}

**Here is the online server directory structure** 
htdocs/{The project will go here}

**My problem**

As you can see, my root directory for the project is "/store" in the localhost environment. So I used relative path in my code to refer to the root directory which is the "/store/". You can see that I use this type of referencing throughout the project.

```
print "<div class='globalerror'>
          <div class='globalerror-content'>
          <h5>Uh-oh! There's an error</h5>
          <p>You must go back</p><br/>
          <p class='back'><a href='/store/'>Go back</a></p>
          </div>
       </div>";
```

If I upload the files to "htdocs" It will give me an error, which is, Directory not found. If I create a folder named "store" inside the htdocs folder... I'd have to go www.mydomain.com/store (which I don't want)

So, did I messed up pretty badly? Or is there a simple fix? Or do I have to edit all the "/store" to "/" in my project?

Comment: So the code you showed, where in the project is it? Where is the file?

Comment: @Loko it's in ...www/store/index.php

Comment: Does using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` work instead of your root stuff?

Comment: @Loko yeah, I guess it'll work. But this is the question isn't it? I have to change all the paths in my code!

Comment: yeah you could do a find & replace in a whole directory and just replace /store/ with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You have to change path of directory. Create new directory and give the path of that directory. Because there is no directory in your server.

Comment: I did, but then It'll go domain.com/store I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you  try URL rewriting with .htacess ?

[URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

If it possible you could change the Folder inside Apache configuration( i presume you use Apache)
[Using a directory in VirtualHost ServerName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552081/using-a-directory-in-virtualhost-servername)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can do modify the .htaccess file and can manage urls, change from store to root

[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280383/php-get-method-without-index-phpid-xxx/36280603#36280603)

[Ref 2](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

[Ref 3](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

The best option is to set the base url in single variable and use the variable around the project.
You can consider the below option, If you are willing to edit the all the links.

**settings.php**

```
/*
Local Server = http://localhost/store/      
Online Server = http://www.example.com/
*/
$WEBSITE_URL = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

**The php files**

Find & Replace  /store/ with $WEBSITE_URL , check the single/double quotes

```
require_once('settings.php');

print "<div class='globalerror'>
          <div class='globalerror-content'>
          <h5>Uh-oh! There's an error</h5>
          <p>You must go back</p><br/>
          <p class='back'><a href='".$WEBSITE_URL."'>Go back</a></p>
          </div>
       </div>";
```