# ReWrite Url With GET Variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have Link :

> http://localhost/account/user?id=123

And i want rewrite to :

> http://localhost/account/user/123

So how i can do that, thanks you.

**UPDATE**

This is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

ErrorDocument 404 https://localhost/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 https://localhost/403.php
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234

Comment: I try but not working, it show 404 Not found . I removed .php from user.php?id=123 to user?id=123 before :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Still not working, how i can use without .php .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this in your htaccess i am assuming user is a php file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```