# how to call rest api by id in php?

Tags: php, rest

now i can output http://localhost/posts/

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "first post",
    "description": "here my first post",
    "status": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "second post",
    "description": "here my second post",
    "status": "Y"
  }
]
```

here my source code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    @List($objnm, $objid) = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
    if ($objnm == 'posts')
    {
        $post = $db->query('SELECT * FROM post WHERE status="Y"');
        echo json_encode($post, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(401);
    }

}
```

my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i need output for http://localhost/posts/1
any one can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite "/book.php?id=1234" to "/book/1234"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest the is_numeric() function to check if the second parameter is a number.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    @List($objnm, $objid) = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
    if ($objnm == 'posts')
    {
        if(is_numeric($objid)) {
            $post = $db->query('SELECT * FROM post WHERE status="Y" AND id="'.$objid.'";');
            echo json_encode($post, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
        else 
        {
            $post = $db->query('SELECT * FROM post WHERE status="Y"');
            echo json_encode($post, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(401);
    }

}
```

Comment: im already change my source code. now i already change my htaccess is not work.

Comment: You can check
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Thanks so much bro. now run ;)