# Need to get the last part of a URL where path doesn't exist

Tags: php

I have the URL of [www.domain.com/profile/user123](http://www.domain.com/profile/user123) (where user123 will vary for each user profile viewed).

How can I get 'user123' into a variable in PHP? I just need to get the very last part of the URL. I don't want to use ? as part of the URL, but right now I'm getting a 404 because the URL doesn't exist.

I'm not sure if I need to modify the .htaccess file? The only modification I have in it so far is to remove .php requirement in URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite "/book.php?id=1234" to "/book/1234"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)

Comment: Welcome we're glad to have you on StackOverflow! To get the most out of your questions please provide as much information as you can regarding what you are wanting to accomplish and what you have tried so far. 
Specifically: Please provide additional information about ".../user123". Is that a php file named user123.php? Is it intended to be a directory? (a directory is what a browser expects)
Is there some reason that you don't want to use URL parameters (the parts of a URL that are after the ? ... and should be key value pairs)??
Please tell us more!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. I edited it the fist answer was wrong. Now it is right.

```
<?php 
$url="www.domain.com/profile/user123";
$arr=explode("/",$url);
$userVariable=end($arr);
?>
```

you can use $userVariable in anywhere on your php document. After triying can you write your result?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as it still shows the page as a 404.

Comment: Before using this code you have modify your htaccess. This code works if the URL is accessible. Than it may help you.

Comment: Filayer - what modification should I make to the .htaccess file?

Comment: can you share your .htaccess file

Comment: Sure - 

# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

Comment: Sorry @Filayer I realise it wasn't marked up correctly.

`code
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
`

Answer (score 0):

if($usr == 'user123')
header ('location: [www.domain.com/profile/'''](http://www.domain.com/profile/%27%27%27));

Comment: Please see [answer] and [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [edit] your post. An answer with an explanation and additional context is more useful than a [code-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). For example, how exactly does this code solve the OPs problem?